# php5-imagick on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, delegates, imagemagick, imagick, ubuntu-14.04

I've spent quite some time googling for this issue, but to no avail, so I was hoping to get some help out here.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and I've installed php5-imagick, ImageMagick and some extra libs for it to function. Testing the installation from the command line works perfectly and all delegates are installed according to 'convert -list configure' (output shown below).

It was working and performing perfectly before. The only thing I can think of is some system/security updates of Ubuntu. My code nor the IM installation were changed by any user actions before this error showed up.

The problem is when I call Imagick from my PHP script, it shows this error:

```
#420: no decode delegate for this image format '/' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/544
```

This error is shown for both JPG and PNG.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

---

**Output of 'convert -version':**

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2014-03-06 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP
```

---

**Output of 'convert -list configure':**

```
DELEGATES     bzlib djvu fftw fontconfig freetype jbig jpeg jng jp2 lcms2 lqr lzma openexr pango png rsvg tiff x11 xml wmf zlib
LIBS          -lMagickCore -llcms2 -ltiff -lfreetype -ljpeg -llqr-1 -lglib-2.0 -lfftw3 -lfontconfig -lfreetype -lXext -lSM -lICE -lX11 -lXt -llzma -lbz2 -lz -lm -lgomp -lpthread -lltdl
```

Comment: I had the same problem once - tough solution was rebuilding the whole server. Bit radical, but I had luck with compiling and building imagemagick myself instead of using the apt package. You could try that out.

Comment: Rebuilding the server is not an option, since it is my development machine. I could try to uninstall imagemagick and recompile/rebuild  the whole thing...

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is that Imagemagick isn't configured to support SVG. Installing basic php5-imagick package doesn't bring in some extras which you'll need for doing this.

To install support for SVG in PHP Imagick type the following into a terminal on the server in question:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libmagickcore5-extra
```

Apt will list a load of dependent packages, including SVG libraries, and will ask you if you'd like to continue. Press Y and let it get on with it.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're trying to open the file named '/'.

Strangely enough Imagick is not able to open that file.

Try passing in a real image filename.

Comment: As I mentioned it concerns both JPG and PNG. I removed the image-path because it was not relevant and it made the error so much longer. But you're right; a file named '/' will not be processed... :) I should've mentioned I altered the image-path.

Answer (score 0):

Check the file to be processed with the vim command. Probably not an image.
I had a similar problem. You can see it here:

[ImageMagick on Ubuntu 14.04 No decode delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36971433/imagemagick-on-ubuntu-14-04-no-decode-delegate)