# ImageMagick on Ubuntu 14.04 No decode delegate

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, imagick, php-5.5

In development enviroment works but not in production enviroment.

**Production enviroment error:**

```
$e->getMessage():
"no decode delegate for this image format 
'/tmp/sws5725c638311df5.24370631' @ error/svg.c/ReadSVGImage/2871"
```

**Generate tmpname:**

```
$tmpname = '/tmp/'.uniqid('sws', true);
```

**Method:**

```
public function load($filename)
  {
    try
    {
      $this->filename = $filename;
      $this->image = new Imagick($filename);
      return $this;
    }
    catch(ImagickException $e)
    {
      error_log($e->getMessage(), 3, "/tmp/log.log");
      OPException::raise(new OPInvalidImageException('Could not create jpeg with ImageMagick library'));
    }
  }
```

**Delegates:**

```
convert -list configure | grep DELEGATES
bzlib djvu fftw fontconfig freetype jbig jpeg jng jp2 lcms2 lqr lzma openexr pango png rsvg tiff x11 xml wmf zlib
```

**Versions (dev and prod enviroments):**

- ImageMagick 6.7.7-10
- Ubuntu 14.04
- PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.16

Any suggestions? Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Huh? You don't show what command you ran. Also, your ImageMagick is ancient and in need of upgrade. Try prefixing your filename with `SVG:` if it doesn't end with `.svg` - assuming it was an SVG file you were trying to process.

Comment: The method is new Imagick($filename). I update my question. Thanks.

Comment: Where does `$tmpname` come into it?

Comment: alditis how did you install Imagick and ImageMagick? @MarkSetchell this will be an installation problem...

Comment: Oh wait, you probably just need to install ghostscript.

Comment: @Danack How can you tell OP is using PDFs?

Comment: Or maybe an svg library...

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I have solved. See my asnwer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Temporary file**

In reviewing the temporary file with the command vim I got the error message coming from the server in XML format and is why the library imagick treated it as svg file.

```
vim /tmp/sws5725c638311df5.24370631
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>RequestTimeTooSkewed</Code>
    <Message>The difference between the request time and the current time is too large.</Message>
    <RequestTime>Sun, 01 May 2016 06:43:17 GMT</RequestTime>
    <ServerTime>2016-05-01T06:28:06Z</ServerTime>
    <MaxAllowedSkewMilliseconds>900000</MaxAllowedSkewMilliseconds>
    <RequestId>382A337F3660C5A9</RequestId>
    <HostId>+2RI3xW5KBd64P13x4yaWly6VdZzn1okvMAYgKvbFYlGnLp87udxpSBCVx7iQNk7zgnkK/ckUXA=</HostId>
</Error>
```

**Solution**

Synchronize time operating system with the server time.

```
sudo service ntp stop
sudo ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com
sudo service ntp start
```

Thanks for the comments.